# Diamond inheritance in Multiple Inheritance using the Virtual keyword

Tags: c++

I've heard that using the virtual keyword solves the diamond problem.

However, when I did this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(int x = 100) {
        num = x;
    }
protected:
    int num;
}; 

class B1 : virtual public A{
public:
    B1(int x = 50) : A(2*x) {
    }
};
class B2 : virtual public A{
public:
    B2(int x = 50) : A(2*x) {
    }
};
class C : public B1, public B2 {
public:
    C(int x = 75) : B1(2*x), B2(2*x) {};
    int getData(){ return num; } 
};

int main() {
    C c(10);

    cout << c.getData(); 
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It displays the output as 100 instead of what I expected, i.e. 40. Why?

Comment: A virtual base class is initialized in the *most derived class* (the type of the actual object you create). Since there's no initializer for `A` in `C`, the argument of `A`'s constructor defaults to 100.

Comment: Or any base class for that matter?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're referring to.

Comment: Forget the diamond. If B inherits A and C inherits B and I only initialize B from C's constructor, then does A get set to default again, i.e. 100?

Comment: A class initializes all its non-virtual direct base classes (and, if it's the most-derived type, also all its virtual base classes). That is, if `B` inherits from `A` nonvirtually, then `B` initializes its *`A` base class subobject*. If `C` inherits from `B`, then `C` does *not* initialize `B`'s *`A` base class subobject*.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10534228/

Comment: @dyp. Please post an answer.

Comment: @Barry I'd rather wield my Mjölnir. Except it's so heavy and I'm kinda tired ;)

Answer (score 2):

When you use virtual inheritance, *you are guaranteed to have one single instance of the common base class* ([cite](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html)); therefore, `B1` and `B2` cannot have their own instance of `A`, but they will share a single instance with `C`. For instance, if you define `C`'s constructor as follows:

```
C(int x = 75) : B1(2*x), B2(2*x), A(x) {};
```

you'll see your code outputs `10`. The key is in what @dyp has commented:

> the common base class is initialized in the most derived class

(Of course in the example above it doesn't make any sense to have all `B1`, `B2` and `A` in the initializer list, as having `A`will suffice).

Comment: Whoooooooooooooooo!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Yes!!! Thanks. I now grasped the concept!