# Getting jumbled constructor calling sequence

Tags: c++, virtual, virtual-inheritance

I am getting a jumbled output for the below program.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;

    public:
        A()
        {
            cout << "A() " << endl;
        }

};

class B : virtual public A
{
    int y;

    public:
        B()
        {
            cout << "B() " << endl;
        }
};

class C : public A
{
    int z;

    public:
        C()
        {
            cout << "C() " << endl;
        }
};

class D1 : public B , public C
{
    int j;

    public:
        D1()
        {
            cout << "D1() " << endl;
        }
};

class D2 : public C, public B
{
    int k;

    public:
        D2()
        {
            cout << "D2() " << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints the output as below.

> A()  B()  A()  C()  D1()  A()  A()  C()  B()  D2()

Where as I was expecting the output as

> A()  B()  A()  C()  D1()  A()  C()  A() B()  D2()

due to the sequence in which I have inherited from the base classes.

It seems that the `virtual` keyword is responsible for jumbling the output.

Can someone please elaborate why is the above behavior when using `virtual` here.

Comment: I my be wrong but why don't you call the constructors of the parent class "initialization_list" style?. Like so:  D2():C(), B() { cout << "D2() " << endl;}. I imagine it will give you greater control and will enlist your compiler to help you if you mess up the order of stuff. I know this won't answer the virtual thing (see the duplicate question) but can help.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan correct that is one way out of the problem , but the question was to determine the behavior.

Comment: Perhaps these might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534228/order-of-constructor-call-in-virtual-inheritance , http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.11 . Both deal with virtual inheritance and calling order of the constructors.